# How can I change my local time zone in Ubuntu, for my time zone doesn’t fit the true situation?

Tags: timezone, ubuntu-18.04

Consider:

[image]

The time in Shanghai should be "(UTC, +0800)", while my computer gives me a surprise.

Comment: In general I think this question would be better suited for https://askubuntu.com/. You might want to [enable clock synchronization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046214/enable-system-clock-synchronization).

Comment: Well, I'll come to that website. Thank you!

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69476787/edit) (it covers command lines and terminal output). Thanks in advance.